# Bit shifting coding efficiency (i.e. neat tricks)

Tags: objective-c, c, bit-shift, bit-manipulation

I'm working on a Objective-C program where I'm getting bitfields over the network, and need to set boolean variables based on those bits.

Currently I'm representing the bitfields as `int`'s, and then using bit shifting, similar to this (all the self properties are BOOL):

```
typedef enum {
    deleteFlagIndex = 0,
    uploadFlagIndex = 1,
    moveFlagIndex = 2,
    renameFlagIndex = 3
} PrivilegeFlagIndex;

int userFlag = 5; //for example

// this would be YES
self.delete = ((userFlag & (1 << deleteFlagIndex)) == (1 << deleteFlagIndex));
// this would be NO
self.upload = ((userFlag & (1 << uploadFlagIndex)) == (1 << uploadFlagIndex));
```

And this works (to the best of my knowledge) but I'm wondering - is there a more <strike>efficient</strike> concise way to code all the bit twiddling using a fancy trick/hack? I ask because I'll be doing this for a *lot* of flags (more than 30).

I did realize I could use this method this as well:

```
self.move = ((userFlag & (1 << moveFlagIndex)) > 0)
```

...which does reduce the amount of typing, but I don't know if there's a good reason to not do it that way.

Edit: Revised to say concise rather than efficient - I wasn't worried about execution performance, but rather tips and best practices for doing this in a smart way.

Comment: "a more efficient way" - more efficient than what? save a few nanoseconds? How do you think the network comms speed compares?

Comment: Do not use any *fancy trick/hack* because **you** will have to understand the code in 2 years! It's not worth saving a few nanos if you're completely using track to achieve that.

Comment: Both good points, especially when dealing with something like bitshifting (which is still hard for me to wrap my head around sometimes). "Efficiency" was probably the wrong word to use, what I really meant was _concise_. I'm definitely not looking to shave off nanoseconds during execution, I was just looking for tips from more experienced programmers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
typedef enum {
    deleteFlag = 1 << 0,
    uploadFlag = 1 << 1,
    moveFlag = 1 << 2,
    renameFlag = 1 << 3
} PrivilegeFlags;
```

Now you can combine them using `|` directly.

Usually, it suffices to check against 0:

```
if (userFlag & deleteFlag) {
    // delete...
}
```

Comment: For the record, checking against 0 will fail if you start using bit masks; imagine the enum had a `modifyFlag = deleteFlag | moveFlag | renameFlag` entry. Just checking `if (userFlag & modifyFlag)` will yield `true` if any of the three bits is set. You'll have to resort to `if ((userFlag & modifyFlag) == modifyFlag)` in this case.

Comment: Sure, if you want to check for multiple bits, you'll have to check for equality with the bit pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to use bitfields and let the compiler do the optimization itself.

Comment: I may experiment with this as well. The bitfield comes across the wire as 8 bytes of data (although only 37 bits of the 64 are currently utilized), and I wasn't sure how to properly cast the data into the bitfield struct I'd set up.